# ROBOCOPY source destination *.* /maxage: <20171231>

Tags: robocopy

I need to copy files from one folder to another,
I want to copy files younger than Dec 31st 2017:
ROBOCOPY source destination *.* /maxage: <20171231>

Answer (score 2):

Here's the link to the documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Maxage is specified in days, so today is 231 days since December 31, so I'd use /maxage:231
(you could use "minlad", if you have last-access-tracking turned on).

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I have a new problem... When all the files I copy over are all hidden and I cant search for files. I did add this /A-:SH to ROBOCOPY source destination *.* /A-:SH .  Searching for the files copied over are still hidden !